# Access MFA enabled github with shell script

Tags: git, shell, github, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to clone a repository from the MFA enabled git repository. I have the username and token code. How can i use these in a shell script?

When we clone the repo from command line, it is asking for username and password (token key). But how can we do the same from shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that i can use the below command

sudo git clone https://{user-name}:{token-code}@{git-clone-link}

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very good idea to hard-code the token in the URL, because anyone who can get access to your repository can find it.  Instead, it's better to use a credential helper and import the value from the environment, like so:

```
export GITHUB_TOKEN= # your token here
GITHUB_URL= # your URL here
git -c credential.helper='f() { echo username=token; password=$GITHUB_TOKEN; };f' \
    clone $GITHUB_URL
```

This is a secure way to pass tokens through the environment which won't result in them appearing in `ps` output for other users or anywhere else in the file.  You can, of course, set your token environment variable to acquire the token from some other method (like a command) as well.